# Python ternary_operator (do-somthing if flag else do-another)

Tags: python, if-statement

Is there method by using python if/else (ternary_operator) to achieve this function:

```
flag = True # or False
if flag:
    print 'abc'
else:
    pass
```

I tried to using:

```
print 'abc' if flag else ''
```

But a blank line will be print if the `flag == False`. Because:

`print 'abc' if flag else ''` **==** `print ('abc' if flag else '')`

Is there any way can make **print nothing** if `flag == False` without using `;`?

Thanks in advance.

---

By the way, I'v tried using `lambda`, but it wasn't successful, here my code:

```
a = lambda x: x if False else None
print a(1)
```

Result:

```
>> python a.py
None
```

Comment: What version of python are you using? In python 2.X print is a statement while in 3.X it's a function.

Comment: His code has it as a statement so I would assume 2.x

Comment: `print` writes the string representation of the object anyway, if you must use the ternary operator you could try `sys.stdout.write('abc' if flag else '')` since it doesn't print a newline, thus nothing gets printed (or you can achieve the same with Python 3.x or importing `print_function` from `__future__` in 2.x with `end=""`)

Comment: Hi @dnet that's really a good way!! But, how could I open a new-file if `flag == False`?

Comment: You cannot print nothing with using Python 2.x `print` statement. You can avoid newline by doing `print '',` but that will still print a single space.

Comment: @Marslo You shouldn't use the ternary operator for such things. Conditional statements (`if ...:`) exist for a reason, and just because Python uses the same keyword (`if`) for the ternary operator, they are two distinct language constructs for two different (although similar) purposes. Use a conditional statement.

Comment: Hi @dnet , Thanks very much! I will chose your answer as accepted answer if you paste your comment as Answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2.X print is a statement while in 3.X print is a function.

You can do `from __future__ import print_function` and print will now be a function. You can then do `print("abc") if condition else None` if you want to print in an expression. Note that the value of the expression is always None, but it may or may not print "abc" depending on the value of `condition`.

You may want to reconsider your programming style. It can be confusing with side-effects, like printing, happening in expressions. Furthermore, Python isn't ideal for functional programming, in my opinion, for a number of reasons. For example:

- There are no proper tail calls so you would easily get stack overflows (or max recursion depth errors).
- You cannot have statements in lambda-expressions. This includes yield statements that otherwise could be used to mitigate the lack of tail calls.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
if flag:
    print "abc"
else:
    # do something else
```

?

Comment: Well, that's good for print, :). But, what if I want to open some-file or do another stuff if flag == False.

Comment: @Marslo, if your else-case does something other than printing, then attempting to use the ternary conditional operator equivalent is misguided in the first place.

Comment: @Marslo The point of the ternary operator is to allow conditions in expressions. It is not Pythonic to write the whole program as an expression.

Comment: Thanks! I just want to know if python can do one thing by different way.

Comment: well, it can, but you really have to force it, as Pythonic design tries to avoid redundancy, see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ (`There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`)

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import print_function
print('abc') if flag else None
```

Comment: This would only work in python 3.X. It looks like the guy is using 2.X.

Comment: As @dnet and @ReyCharles mentioned, in python2.x, we can use `from __future__ import print_function` to make print as function.